# Nearly locally presentable categories

Tags: category-theory, functors, representable-functor, hom-functor, locally-presentable-categories

[Here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/33/10/33-10.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, in the remark $2.3 (1)$ how from the fact that ${\cal K}(A,-)$ **does not preserve coproducts** it follows that ${\cal K}(A,-)$ sends special $\lambda$-directed colimits to $\lambda$-directed colimits and **not to special** $\lambda$-directed ones?

<sup>1</sup>
Leonid Positselski, Jiří Rosický: *Nearly locally presentable categories*,
Theory and Appl. of Categories 33 (2018), #10, p.253-264;
http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/33/10/33-10abs.html https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10476

Comment: To preserve special directed colimits, which are by definition always coproducts, just with a richer diagram shape than the discrete one, you would have to preserve coproducts.

Comment: I do not follow the meaning of the middle part of your sentence: "[] just with a richer diagram shape than the discrete one"

Comment: It's a coproduct expressed as a filtered colimit of sub-coproducts of up to size $\lambda$ rather than as a discrete colimit. But it's still required to be a coproduct.